# Отсортировать двумерный массив по строкам одного столбца

Tags: c++, c, массивы, сортировка, c++builder

Объясню очень просто: есть 2-а столбца и 5000 строк, в 1 столбце числа от 0 до 4999, во втором рандомные числа. Вот пример:

```
[0][42]
[1][23]
[2][44]
[3][123]
[4][80]
[5][19]
```

Нужно упорядочить второй столбец так, чтобы числа в первом соответствовали второму. Вот пример:

```
[5][19]
[1][23]
[0][42]
[2][44]
[4][80]
[3][123]
```

Это мне нужно для бинарного поиска.

Comment: "чтобы числа в первом соответствовали второму" - не совсем понятно. А двумерный массив это прям строго? Почему бы не использовать set, который хранит объект - две пары чисел + ф-ция сортировки?

Comment: Так задал преподавтлель, это нужно чтобы при поиске элементов линейным и бинарным методом, у чисел был 1 и тот же индекс

Comment: вы - лекции прогуливаете, а мы за вас задачки решаем? :)

Comment: Я лекции не прогуливаю, просто практика и лекции в рознь идут, я могу сортировать массивы, но только полностью, а не целые строки по значениям одного столбца. И программирование у меня автомат уже, я просто другу помогаю, всем разную защиту дают.

Comment: @Tark  Я так и не понял. Вы человеческий язык знаете? Что вам нужно сделать? Отсортировать строки матрицы по значениям во втором столбце?

Comment: Да именно это мне и нужно, сортировать строку целиком, по значениям второго столбца

Comment: @Tark  Укажите точно,  какой язык используется C или C++?

Comment: используется C++ Builder 6, у него немного свой синтаксис.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы должны использовать собственную сортировку методом выбора, то ее код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    size_t min = i;

    for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++ )
    {
        if ( mas[j][1] < mas[min][1] )
        {
            min = j;
        }
    }

    if (min != i)
    {
        int tmp[2] = { mas[i][0], mas[i][1] };
        mas[i][0] = mas[min][0]; mas[i][1] = mas[min][1];
        mas[min][0] = tmp[0]; mas[min][1] = tmp[1];
    }
}
```

тип `size_t` можете заменить на тип `int`, если переменная `N` имеет тип `int`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё отлично работает)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала определите функцию сравнения

```
bool cmp(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    return a[1] < b[1];
}
```

Затем выполните `sort`

```
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), cmp);
```

C++ у меня не основной язык, по памяти мог что-то не так написать.

---

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++) 
{ 
    x=mas_order[i]; 
    j=i-1;
        while (j>=0 && x[1]<mas_order[j][1]) 
        {
            mas_order[j+1]=mas_order[j];
            j=j-1;
        }
    mas_order[j+1]=x; 
}
```

Comment: всё бы хорошо, но нас пока не обучали функциям, и это будет очень заметно.

Comment: @Tark тогда приведите код, который вы используете для сортировки обычного массива, я его подкорректирую

Comment: вроде указано, что надо "Отсортировать двумерный массив"

Comment: 'for (i=1;i<N;i++)
        {
        x=mas_order[i];
        j=i-1;
        while (j>=0 && x<mas_order[j])
                {
                mas_order[j+1]=mas_order[j];
                j=j-1;
                }
        mas_order[j+1]=x;
        }

Comment: Не понимаю как корректно вставить код, но сортировка происходит методом включения

Comment: так же можно использовать метод пузырьком, или выбором

Comment: @Tark просто лень было код искать. Посмотри, обновил. Используй просто [1] в сравнении

Comment: Он не может выполнить условие x=mas_order[i]; так как mas_order двумерный массив.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось что то вроде этого но всё равно не работает, он сортирует 2-ой столбец и в первом выполняет записи по второму столбцу. сохраняя индекс у числа второго столбца, но не работает, не знаю что уже делать с этим двумерным массивом(

```
int Nmin,min1,min2;
for (int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
        {
        Nmin=i;
        min1=mas[i][1];
        min2=mas[i][0];
        for (int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
                {
                if (min1>mas[j][1])
                        {
                        min1=mas[j][1];
                        min1=mas[j][0];
                        Nmin=j;
                        }
                }
        mas[Nmin][1]=mas[i][1];
        mas[Nmin][0]=mas[i][0];
        mas[i][1]=min1;
        mas[i][0]=min2;
        }
```